# Is it right and polite to ask for a free copy of a published paper?

Tags: publications, etiquette

There is a published research paper I would like to read. The website it is published in, charges what I think is quite a lot of money, considering that I won't use this for research or work.

I want to read this paper because its about a subject I am really interested in, but has nothing to do with what I study. I am a software engineering student and had never participated on any kind of research and I do not quite understand how all this things work.

So, the question is: is it right to ask for a copy of this paper to its author? If it is, how should I do it?

Comment: Sometimes, it is important to explain why you are interested in the paper.

Comment: Our present norms and customs, including contracts that authors sign with journals, often contain a huge amount of archaic weirdness based on how things were in the 20th century. Before the internet, people used to request paper reprints from authors. That made sense then. What you're describing is a situation where we reproduce that custom in the modern era, where it doesn't make sense. An example of what would make sense would be for the author to use a preprint server such as arxiv. Authors want their work to be widely read. If journals make that harder, then journals are the enemy.

Comment: It should be noted that most universities will provide access to their students to papers that are behind a 'paywall'. Ask your library on information for how to get access to such papers.

Comment: I would be more than happy if anyone wanted to ask for my papers; just sayin'

Comment: _in the modern era, where it doesn't make sense_ — What?  Of course it makes sense, especially if the paper is in a discipline whose authors still follow the archaic practice of not making their papers freely available on the web.  And by that, I mean _most_ disciplines.

Comment: @JeffE: maybe Ben meant to put emphases on the word "paper reprints"? I would be more than happy to e-mail copies of my papers to people who want it, but if they person writes to ask for an offprint, I would either politely decline (of my published papers only 1 journal has ever sent me any offprints) or just completely ignore.

Comment: I assume you've looked for an institutional repository at the lead author's institution - they're often but not always found by googling the paper title in quotes with `site:inst.edu` as well.  At least here in the UK some public libraries are getting some journal access, that might be worth looking into.

Comment: If I were you, I would move my attention towards the OpenScience Movement .
A lot of great people are working there and it is quite likely that you will find a paper of related content for FREE :-) A great place to start is the Figshare data repository (http://figshare.com/) Also, in my personal opinion, I think knowledge should be free and paying for knowledge is unacceptable .

Comment: Related: "[Is it rude to request a book chapter from the academic who wrote it if you don't want to buy the entire textbook?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15413/10518)"

Comment: What's the paper?

Comment: Perhaps not relevant for your question, but if you ask someone for a copy of a paper, and then you cite it in one of your own papers, I think it is good manners to mention in your paper's acknowledgements "We thank X for supplying offprints."

Comment: @Senex However, I suspect the most important thing is you citing it :-).

Answer (score 59):

I don't think that it could be a problem to ask politely for a copy of this paper. It is understood, however, that you are polite and say thank you.

So, if you are interested, you should show it that way. It doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 39):

Use a search engine to see if there's a free copy online – many authors put their papers on their own websites and, in some fields, on ArXiv or other repositories.

Ask your university's library if they already have access to a free copy online or have it on paper – libraries subscribe to as many journals as they can afford to and may also be able to obtain a copy from another library at less cost than from the publisher.

If neither of those options work, politely email the corresponding author (if there is one, or any author, if there isn't) and ask for a copy.

Comment: While "libraries subscribe to as many journals as they can afford to" is true and it cannot hurt to ask, the OP shouldn't get their hopes up too much as usually, if a library has a subscription for something behind a paywall, the respective university network will be recognized by the document server and the documents will be accessible when invoked from within that network. At least in my place, whenever I ever get to see a paywall on an academic publisher's site, it is sufficiently safe to say that my university does *not* have a subscription that would cover the respective publication.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Good point -- thanks for bringing it up. It's possible, though, that the OP tried to download the paper from a computer at home (perhaps I just inferred too much from the OP *not* saying something like "I tried to download it from a university computer but it was still paywalled").

Comment: This would have been my answer, though I would like to add the minor point that in Mathematics, Physics, and Computer Science, authors often post their papers to arXiv.org, even when it has been submitted simultaneously to a journal.

Comment: If you have access to a university library it is worth asking their advice - if you are a student there they will often be able to request it from another library via a reciprocal agreement at a much lower cost than buying from the publisher. Or, depending where you are, try a national library - e.g. the British Library is open to UK-based people.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It might be an old paper and the university library might have a dead-trees copy.

Comment: @gerrit: As the question said the paper is published "in [a] website", I implicitly assumed this is about a sufficiently new paper to be published and distributed digitally. Otherwise, you may of course be right.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This is certainly true sometimes, but not always. For example where I did my PhD, it would only recognize that you were going through the university and grant access when using the wired network (rather than the wireless).

Comment: In my experience there are a bunch of psychology journals for which my own university has a subscription but where the process is more complicated than just visiting via a university proxy.

Answer (score 32):

There is an issue with this question in that one request "is no request" but if this becomes systematic, each author starts to become a "server" for their papers. I am sure no-one would want to end up in that situation.

I personally do not mind if someone asks for a particular paper as long as they also engage in some scientific discussion on why they want it. There is of course no rule that says you must do that other than common courtesy. Fortunately, I am not in a position to get many requests but back in the day of paper reprints, it was known that some persons (still scientists) were simply collectors who wrote and asked for every paper that was published.

So in the end, if you really have use for a specific paper and you have a hard time finding it, don't hesitate to ask. Saying a few words about why you are interested in the paper may start up a positive conversation on the topic and your interest. The main point is: make it a positive event.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph: a scientific article that cannot be obtained with friction close to the minimum allowed by technology is lost to science. An author who put himself or herself in a position where he or she is the limit factor in disseminating his or her work has renounced science, and might as well take a new occupation, such as patent lawyer. ArXiv is your friend, and so is dumping the article in the public domain before the publisher can extort the copyright out of you.

Comment: "each author starts to become a "server" for their papers" -- at least that would be an incentive to put a free version (preprint) on a computer server.

Answer (score 31):

I am always thrilled when someone asks for a copy of one of my journal papers, because I have adopted the pessimistic view that this stuff never gets read.  So yes, feel free to ask, so long as you are polite.  And as someone else pointed out, it wouldn't hurt to indicate why you want to read the paper.

Answer (score 19):

Yes.

I've asked authors for copies of papers several times, always with a note about what in my own research led me to take an interest in that particular paper. The authors have always said yes. One even dug up an old paper copy and scanned it for me. I got the impression each time that they were delighted to hear that their work was relevant and interesting for new scholarship.

Usually the authors' agreements with their publishers allow them to make single copies on request, so legalities are not normally a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the authors' point of view it won't hurt to send the paper to someone who asks nicely (unless the corresponding author is the top scientist in the field and gets many unsolicited emails).

Check whether the author has profiles in research networks such as https://www.researchgate.net and ask them through the site's options. This is particularly better for those who keep their profiles up to date, as it gives you more potential of a networking than a mere email.